# Valid/possible to declare get/set for a property that's being declared as public in constructor in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

If I have a class like this:

```
export class Thing{
  constructor(private some: string) { ... }
  get thing() { return this.some; }
  set thing(value: string) { this.some = value; } 
}
```

I wonder if this is a proper way to have a controlled property (by get and set) with a backing field that is assignable from constructor. Is there a simpler way to do this?

One way would be of, of course, to do this:

```
export class Thing{
  constructor(public some: string) { ... }
}
```

but then we have only control over set in the initial stage. Another would be:

```
export class Thing{
  constructor(private some: string) { ... }
}
```

but then we have no access to it publicly. And only using set/get makes it impossible to set while creating the object.

Comment: If you need to do custom code inside get and set and you also want to use a different backing field, I don't see how it can get much simpler than the first case.  If you are just trying to prevent users from setting a public field, you can mark it `readonly` (with caveats).  I'm confused about what you're trying to simplify.

Comment: @jcalz I discovered **by coincidence** that I could set the params to constructor as public to make them properties. Earlier, I discovered **by mistake** that not setting public/void on method declarations means they are there implicitly. Loving the compact syntax, I'm always asking myself if my code can be improved. Regrettably, judging from your comment, the answer is "no" in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing it the correct way in your question, assuming you are going to use the getter and setter for a purpose:

```
export class Thing {
  constructor(private some: string) { ... }
  get thing() { return this.some; }
  set thing(value: string) { this.some = value; } 
}
```

If your getter and setter really are as plain as this example, there is little benefit over your other example:

```
export class Thing {
  constructor(public thing: string) { ... }
}
```

Comment: There's a purpose, indeed. I just omitted it for the sake of brevity and to-the-point'ness.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I thought that might be the case :)